# Python - tkinter.messagebox with DLL resource icons

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, messagebox

By default, `tkinter.messagebox` uses 4 icons located in `user32.dll` resource. (or other that look like that)

[image]

---

However, when browsing resource DLL files in Nirsoft IconsExtract utility, I found some fancy icons located in `comres.dll` file.

[image]

### Is there a way to change message box icons by resource and ID? `<File>.dll,-<ID>` (or other method)

##### *But why, in the first place?*

Just for design purpose - there are thousands of icons in these files, and they may provide *a fresh look*, so why not?

```py
messagebox.showinfo(
    title = "Success",
    message = "File has been converted successfully.",
    icon = "imageres.dll,-1405"
)
```

[image]

---

Browsing tkinter source code is just a waste of time, since it contains a lot of references that don't lead anywhere, as shown below:

```py
    s = master.tk.call(self.command, *master._options(self.options))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bad -icon value "imageres.dll,-1405": must be error, info, question, or warning
```

I believe that there is a way to do this with `win32api`, `ctypes` and more Windows-specific Python modules. **How?**

Comment: You need icon from folder. Here is link https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons/

Answer (score 2):

Studying the source Python library code, you can see the internal Tk call ends up being made to `tk_messageBox`. Here's the doc for it: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/messageBox.html

Per the doc:

> -icon iconImage
> Specifies an icon to display. IconImage must be one of the following: `error`, `info`, `question` or `warning`. If this option is not specified, then the `info` icon will be displayed.

Because of that, you can't change the icon of the message box, because the underlaying Tkinter won't accept any other value there. I'm pretty sure the simplest way to get around this would be to create your own version of a message box via a new root window, add in two labels, set one of them as the icon image and make the other one display text, and then add the needed buttons to it.

Or, you can try investigating `tk_dialog` instead: The doc suggests there is a possibility it'd do what you wanted: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/dialog.html

Python defines a module for it under `tkinter.dialog`. You can call it's `_test` function to see some example window for it. Here's the module source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/dialog.py

Test code:

```py
from tkinter import dialog
dialog._test()
```

You can also run the module itself as it has a `__main__` clause defined: `python -m tkinter.dialog`. Here's the window it shows to me:

[image]